# TypeError: send_photo() got an unexpected keyword argument 'caption'

Tags: python, linux, telegram

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Написала простенький бот для телеграмма, на windows работает исправно.
Перенесла его на Linux(Debian) server и уже не работает. 
Код бота:
[скриншот]

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "BotBeta.py", line 17, in <module>
    bot.send_photo(CHANNEL_NAME, open('/home/Bots1/GalleryBot/files/2.jpg', 'rb'), caption = d.read())
TypeError: send_photo() got an unexpected keyword argument 'caption'
```

Перебровала всё, оборачивала "d" в print, отображается нормально. Запускаю командой python3 Bot.py(просто python на линуксе вызывает второй и там уже ругается на "utf-8")

Опять же, самое странное что на `Windows` работает, а `linux` кажется сам бот даже не реагирует(

Comment: Директории в коде под линукс, разумеется, другие:
"/home/Bots1/GalleryBot/files/posttext.txt"
"/home/Bots1/GalleryBot/files/2.jpg"

Comment: код в виде текста (с форматированием) вставьте  в вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting Не помещайте информацию необходимую для ответа в комментарии к собственному вопросу.

Comment: что `python3 -mpip show telebot` выводит на Linux и Windows (`py -3 -mpip show telebot`)

Answer (score 0):

возможно, у вас установлена другая бибиотека,
попробуйте pip3 install pytelegrambotapi

Comment: это ничего, что в вопросе речь о пакете `telebot`?